# Use unittest assertRaise() with object instantiation

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a class FilePlay that accepts three parameters `host_dic`,`PATH`, `group` all with default values. When the host_dic is given the object instantiation will create a file. When not given the object instantiation will check if the file exists, if not will raise an error. Here is the code:

```
class FilePlay(object):
    def __init__(self, host_dic=None, PATH='/foo/', group='bar'):
        self.host_dic = host_dic
        self.PATH = PATH
        self.group = group # this changes with the instantiation

        if isinstance(hosts_dic, dict):
            # create a file
            # change self.group
        else:
            if os.path.isfile(self.PATH+'hosts'):
                # read the file
                # change self.group
            else:
                raise IOError("Neither hosts file found nor host_dic parameter given, cannot instantiate.")
```

Now I would like to test this with `unittest`. So here is my code:

```
import unittest
from top.files import FilePlay
import os.path  


class Test_FilePlay(unittest.TestCase):

def test_init_PATH(self):
    '''It tests FilePlay instatiation when:
       PATH parameter is given
    '''
    test_PATH='/foo/'

    if not os.path.isfile(test_PATH+'hosts'): # If there is no hosts file at PATH location
        self.assertRaises(IOError,play = FilePlay(PATH=test_PATH)) #Here is the problem!
    else: # if there is the hosts file at PATH location
        play = FilePlay(PATH=test_PATH)

        self.assertEqual(play.group, 'bar')
        self.assertEqual(play.hosts_dic, None)
```

When i try to run the test with the file at the PATH location it works ok. But when the file is NOT present I get:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_init_PATH (top.tests.test_test_file)
It tests FilePlay instatiation when:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "top/tests/test_file.py", line 14, in test_init_PATH
    self.assertRaises(IOError,play = FilePlay(PATH=test_PATH))
  File "top/ansible_shared.py", line 88, in __init__
    raise IOError("Neither hosts file found nor host_dic parameter given, cannot instantiate.")
IOError: Neither hosts file found nor host_dic parameter given, cannot instantiate.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

How could pass the test when the file is NOT present?

Comment: Why would you need to assign to a name if calling `FilePlay` raises an exception? The `play = ` part plays no role. By calling `FilePlay` directly the exception is raised before the `assertRaises()` method can be called. And don't make your test conditional on the presence of a file. Test both scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. An example would really help..

Comment: You have the answer below already.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Are u suggesting to remove the if/else and just use the self.assert* statements one after the other? thanks

Comment: I'd split this out into two tests; one where the path doesn't exist, the other with a mocked `os.path.isfile()` function (and other mocks) to test the case where the file is to be loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using `assertRaises` correctly. You're calling the object directly, so that the error is raised before the assertion has a chance to capture it.

You need to either pass the class itself and its parameters separately:

```
self.assertRaises(IOError, FilePlay, PATH=test_PATH)
```

or use the context manager version:

```
with self.assertRaises(IOError):
    FilePlay(PATH=test_PATH)
```

Comment: Thank you that works fine! I don't know about the context manager. I will look it up